# Is the Postfix From: address RFC-compliant for cron jobs?

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-18.04

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server with Postfix configured to send through a local network mail relay.

Only when a message is generated by `cron` does it include the following in the `From:` header:

```
From: root@relayclient.example.com (Cron Daemon)
```

All other messages from the server are as expected:

```
From: root@relayclient.example.com
```

This is causing an issue for the relay DKIM signing and seems out of conformance with RFC 5322. My reading of [3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.4) and [Appendix A.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#appendix-A.5) is that the address most likely should be:

```
From: <root@relayclient.example.com> (Cron Daemon)
```

However, I may be misunderstanding the RFC and there is some other problem.

Here is the current configuration, which is pretty much just the default "satellite" configuration created by the `postfix` package:

`postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, relayclient.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
myhostname = relayclient.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 192.0.2.85
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

`cat /etc/aliases`:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
root:          admin@example.net
```

`cat /etc/mailname`:

```
relayclient.example.com
```

Comment: Why do you think it is "out of conformance with RFC"?

Comment: My understanding of [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.4) is that it should be `Cron Daemon <root@relayclient.example.com`>, but could also be `<root@relayclient.example.com>` or `root@relayclient.example.com`.

Comment: Check the RFC 5322 appendix for comments example.

Comment: I just reviewed the appendix, and it seems like all of the examples conform to my current understanding. Did I somehow miss one that you are thinking of?

Comment: @AlexD Okay, so [A.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#appendix-A.5) does give examples such as: `John <jdoe@one.test> (my dear friend); (the end of the group)`, but even in that example the address is within `< >`, but the address in the mail generated from cron jobs is not.

Comment: (...) is a "CFWS" part from the specification. See [3.2.2.  Folding White Space and Comments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the spec also includes [comments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.2.2):

> Strings of characters enclosed in parentheses are considered comments
> so long as they do not appear within a "quoted-string", as defined in
> section 3.2.4.  Comments may nest.
>
> There are several places in this specification where comments and FWS
> may be freely inserted.  To accommodate that syntax, an additional
> token for "CFWS" is defined for places where comments and/or FWS can
> occur.

EBNF (I ommited non-relevant tokens):

```
address         =   mailbox / group
mailbox         =   name-addr / addr-spec
name-addr       =   [display-name] angle-addr
angle-addr      =   [CFWS] "<" addr-spec ">" [CFWS] / obs-angle-addr
display-name    =   phrase

FWS             =   ([*WSP CRLF] 1*WSP) /  obs-FWS
ctext           =   %d33-39 /          ; Printable US-ASCII
                    %d42-91 /          ;  characters not including
                    %d93-126 /         ;  "(", ")", or "\"
                    obs-ctext
ccontent        =   ctext / quoted-pair / comment
comment         =   "(" *([FWS] ccontent) [FWS] ")"
CFWS            =   (1*([FWS] comment) [FWS]) / FWS
```

Notice `comment` token includes literal parenthesis, and the CFWS could be this comment (with whitespace around) or the whitespace itself. This part in the parethesis appears right at the end of the `angle-addr` token, where comment is allowed. So this `(Cron Daemon)` is a `CFWS`, *"comment or folding white space"* token, and therefore **the address as spelled fully conforms with the spec.**

Also there is a special note about naked `addr-spec` with the `comment`:

> Note: Some legacy implementations used the simple form where the
> addr-spec appears without the angle brackets, but included the
> name of the recipient in parentheses as a comment following the
> addr-spec.  Since the meaning of the information in a comment is
> unspecified, implementations SHOULD use the full name-addr form of
> the mailbox, instead of the legacy form, to specify the display
> name associated with a mailbox.  Also, because some legacy
> implementations interpret the comment, comments generally SHOULD
> NOT be used in address fields to avoid confusing such
> implementations.

Comment: Man, there is something I'm really missing here, because when I read that I see `[CFWS] "<" addr-spec ">" [CFWS] / obs-angle-addr`, and the messages from cron jobs are more like `addr-spec [CFWS]`, which does not seem the same to me.

Comment: The real answer is in Note about legacy address form in section 3.4 of RFC 5322

Comment: True. I misread the question. However, that note is exactly answers the question.

Comment: When it states "...name of the recipient in parentheses" is `(Cron Daemon)` the recipient? It seems like the daemon generating the message.

Comment: And then: "... the meaning of the information in a comment is unspecified...". I think it was just a bad wording to call that thing in parentheses "name of the recipient" that added a meaning unintentionally.

Comment: Indeed, it seems worded poorly. On reading again I think it means "some legacy implementations [one example of legacy usage]...".

Comment: @Paul the usage of format `person@example.com (Person Name)` was common (`mutt` or `mail` still understand it) but, syntactically, the content in parentheses is just a comment and its usage as 'Display Name' of the sender or recipient wasn't specified in the standard.